# Deploy WindowsForms com banco .mdf

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

Fiz um programinha em Windows Forms (C#) em camadas.

- Model
- DAO
- BLL
- Interface

Criar no Projeto Model um Banco (Gerador.mdf) e seu Context (edmx).

Agora quero publicar, e como faço para que o arquivo .mdf venha junto com o publish?

*Obs: Se eu por tudo num unico projeto, funciona!*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Nas propriedades do arquivo Gerador.mdf, selecione em "Copy to Output Directory" ou "Copy always" para o arquivo ser sempre copiado para o diretório de saída ou "Copy if newer" para copiar somente se o arquivo mais recente que o existente no diretório de saída.

Comment: Não funcionou!!

Comment: Por enquanto a unica solução esta sendo adicionar o .mdf file como item no projeto principal.

Comment: realmente não sei como não funcionou, você conseguiu alterar corretamente a propriedade ? se você alterou busque por esse arquivo Gerador.mdf na pasta onde você joga os arquivos do Publish, eu testei aqui e ele jogou o arquivo pra pasta bin